# How to filter a Pie chart by selection in table

Tags: powerbi, dax, pie-chart, powerbi-desktop

Please consider this scenario:

I have a table in `Power-BI` that's like this:

```
Country           Total Sales
-----------------------------
USA               2000
Canada            1400
Spain             3200
```

And I want to have a `Pie` chart in page that if user clicks on every rows, The pie shows sales type for that `Country`. For Example:

[image]

How can I connect these to visuals together?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two visuals shows data from the same data source, then they will be "connected" by default, i.e. when the user clicks on a row in the table, the pie chart will show only the data from the selected country, and if the user clicks on a sector from the chart, the table will show only the amounts for this category.

If you have a table in your data source like this:

[image]

Then add a table in the report with columns `Country` and `Sales` like this:

[image]

By default amounts will be aggregated as sum, so the table will show sum of Sales per Country. You can change the default summarization of the currently selected field in `Modeling` tab:

[image]

Add a pie chart with Category field in the legend and Sales field for value. Change the value to be shown as percentage from the grand total like this:

[image]

Adding Sales field as tooltip will also show the amount when pointing to a sector:

[image]

Now when you click on a row in the table, the pie chart will show only the relevant data:

[image]

For more information take a look at [Change how visuals interact in a Power BI report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions) and [Filters and highlighting in Power BI reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-reports-filters-and-highlighting) articles.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not work if the pie chart is top-N pie chart. I open a [new issue](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=3bc8b83e-ba45-ec11-a3ee-501ac50a7893) to the Power BI community to fix it. Here is a description of the issue: Basically, I have a top-N pie chart created for states. But, when I select a city in a table and the city is not in one of those states, the pie chart is not updated to show the state of the selected city. Instead, it remains to show those top-N states with 0% in every slices. This is wrong. It should show the top-N states of the "selected" cities.